# bintray creating directories claims to upload artificats but it's blank

Tags: gradle, bintray

We are evaluating bintray and have the following build file

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/evaluateBintray/build.gradle

(not sure the build file matters since it reports that it is uploading each and every artifact correctly).  I see stuff like this...

```
> Task :webserver-plugins:plugin-backend:bintrayUpload
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19-sources.jar'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19-javadoc.jar...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19-javadoc.jar'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19.jar...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19.jar'.
Uploading to https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19.pom...
Uploaded to 'https://api.bintray.com/content/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend/2.0.19/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19/plugin-backend-2.0.19.pom'.
```

The really weird part though is it would create directories

```
https://dl.bintray.com/deanhiller/maven/org/webpieces/plugin-backend/2.0.19
```

but nothing is there until I deploy everything then the files show up.  It seems kind of odd that the directories are created but there are no files in the upload phase.  Then, my final question is, are these artifacts only available there, or are they published to jcenter or maven central as well.  I can't really tell.

We are trying bintray to maybe switch off of sonatype because every time we upload, we get exceptions on sonatype(for last 4 days we have not been able to release).  In bintray so far, every single upload has been successful(176 artifacts in one go).

Possibly I need more stuff to get this stuff out to jcenter or maven central?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

I do see these files at the moment.

If the artifacts are not `published` then only **authorized** users can view and download the content, this means that unauthorized users, such as anonymous, will not see content in your [download repository](https://dl.bintray.com/deanhiller/maven/org/webpieces/plugin-backend).

Your [package](https://bintray.com/deanhiller/maven/plugin-backend) is not linked to [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) therefore they are not automatically published on jcenter.
I would suggest to [include your packages](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories#CentralRepositories-IncludingyourPackageinJCenter) to jcenter.